# SpriteKit gravity falling objects erratic jitters/choppiness

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm generating random falling SKSpriteNode objects in my scene. I noticed that sometimes the falling objects fall smoothly and sometimes they are jittery. It is more noticeable when I set the gravity at -4. I've been trying to figure out this erratic behavior but no success. However, I noticed also that the choppiness seems to disappear when I transition to a different scene and then transition back - sometimes I have to do it several times. The scene is running at a consistent 60fps even if the objects fill the screen. I've checked for areas where I might be bogging down the flow but even if I remove those possible areas it did not help. Has anyone experienced this behavior before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too many other unknowns to answer your question. Is the falling object running or starting an animation during the fall? Are there other things happening to cause CPU usage to increase? Etc...

Comment: No animation and not running any actions. I just have a dropObject(atLocation). The objects have a physics body so the collide with each other. What boggles my mind is that sometimes they run smoothly and sometimes they are jittery. I've also check CPU usage and it doesn't seem to matter wether it's at low 20% or high 90% usage. The same behavior happens. The only predictable test that I've narrowed down to remove the choppiness is when I transition to a different scene and then transition back.

Comment: I've finally worked it out. I had to set physicsWorld.speed   0.9999 instead of 1.0.